# Does .previousSibling always return the parent's Text node first?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm stuck using native DOM methods (I know, right?) and I have a structure like this:

```
<div>
    <input>
    <a>
</div>
```

I'm using an onClick on the `<a>` tag, and want to retrieve the value from the input. On Chrome/OS X, something like

```
this.previousSibling.previousSibling.value
```

will work well. I double it though because the first `.previousSibling` returns the `<div>`'s Textnode, and one more before that gets the input that I want.

My question is: does `.previousSibling` always return the parent's text node if it exists?

Thanks!

### **EDIT / Solution**

My hacky solution was (cross browser) to ensure I get the right element looked like this:

```
var el = this; 
while(el.nodeType == 3 || el.tagName && el.tagName !== 'INPUT') {
    el = el.previousSibling
}; 
console.log(el.value);
```

Location specific, but works cross browser, and is light enough to toss into an `onClick` for my needs. Thanks for the help in figuring out what was at issue here (line breaks between HTML in particular)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does .previousSibling always return the parent's text node if it
>   exists?

No. It returns the immediately preceding sibling. In your case, there is a text node (a new line) immediately preceding the `a` element, so it returns that.

If you remove the white space it should work as expected:

```
<div>
    <input><a></a> <!-- input is immediately preceding anchor -->
</div>
```

However, that's not a particularly nice solution. See @Esailija's answer for a nicer one!

Comment: Ah, this is why I was confused. I didn't know why (what I thought was) the main child text node of the Div would be spliced between children [0] and [1]. Thanks a lot James.

Answer (score 9):

It returns the previous sibling node, it might be `text node`, it might be `element node`, it might be `null`

You can retrieve previous element nodes with `.previousElementSibling` which isn't supported in legacy browsers but you can use a function like:

```
function previousElementSibling( elem ) {

    do {

        elem = elem.previousSibling;

    } while ( elem && elem.nodeType !== 1 );

    return elem;
}
```

`previousElementSibling(this)` will result in the input element.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://www.w3schools.com/dom/prop_element_previoussibling.asp

> The previousSibling property returns the previous sibling node (the
>   previous node in the same tree level) of the selected element
>
> If there is no such node, this property returns null.

technically, what you're showing there is

```
<div><textnode><input><textnode><a><textnode></div>
```

...so if the browsers are following the rules, it should keep working properly.  If you're asking whether or not there are browsers out there that fail to follow the rules on this, I can't help you, but I will note that IE has a habit of adding dom objects to pages (particularly as wrappers) which might prove hazardous regardless.

Edit: http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_nodes_navigate.asp has this to say on the topic.

> Firefox, and some other browsers, will treat empty white-spaces or new
>   lines as text nodes, Internet Explorer will not.