# Hide previoussibling in Javascript

Tags: javascript

HTML:

```
<label>First Name</label>
<input type="text" value="" id="FNAME">
```

JS:

```
var FNAME = document.getElementById('FNAME');

FNAME.addEventListener('input', function() {
  if (FNAME.value !== ''){
    alert('Field not empty! Value: '+ FNAME.value);
    document.getElementById('FNAME').previousSibling.style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
});
```

... gives an error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'FNAME.previousSibling.style')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `FNAME` is a **string**. Use `document.getElementById("FNAME").prev...`

Comment: You are trying to access previousSibling with value. try to access it with object `document.getElementById("FNAME").previousSibling.style.visibility = "hidden"`

Comment: @Tushar Updated, but still the same.

Comment: Can you add complete code and/or live demo

Comment: First check if `document.getElementById("FNAME").previousSibling` is defined. What do you get there?

Comment: @CharlieH https://jsfiddle.net/c5dy8xrr/1/ I do get the DOM element in console.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Sorry, updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append `previousSibling` to `previousSibling` again. It should correctly target the label now.

```
  var FNAME = document.getElementById('FNAME');
  if (FNAME.value !== ''){
    var label = FNAME.previousSibling.previousSibling.style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
```

Comment: As I explained in my answer, the `previousSibling` is the spaces between elements. Maybe this would do it right: `<label for="FNAME">First Name</label><input type="text" value="" id="FNAME">`

Comment: The first `previousSibling` targets the text node (the line break), the second targets the element.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question regarding the error you get, `previousSibling` of your `input` is a text node (the white space between the `label` and `input`). And text nodes do not have a style property.

Now, as far as I understand your question, you want to hide the label under certain conditions.

I would change your `html` a bit and use some more modern js api to access the elements.

```
<label for="FNAME">First Name</label>
<input type="text" value="" id="FNAME">
```

here I added the `for` property to the label.

```
var FNAME = document.querySelector("#FNAME");
var label = document.querySelector("label[for='FNAME']")

FNAME.addEventListener('input', function() {
  if (FNAME.value !== ''){
    alert('Field not empty! Value: '+ FNAME.value);
    label.style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
});
```

hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

The previous sibling of your input element is it's text node.

So, you should call `FNAME.previousSibling.previousSibling` to access the label.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008732/does-previoussibling-always-return-the-parents-text-node-first) question would give you more info.