# Change Div which comes in DOM before UL-element

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I have the following code( https://jsfiddle.net/weemoLya/3/ ):

```
<div style="padding: 0px 41px 14px; line-height: 15pt;"><span style="font-family: georgia;">Anwoarnoernb&nbsp; bneobnoqbno nb bnorgneoüqrgn beoünbeoütnboetuübn nbwetiobnweoütnho übnoet wübn weton<br />

otnwboün boenbhiowt nb etiopwogj weto&nbsp; getiogei oeghqeogje ghqeoü gheoügneoqüh<br />
<br />
Ihre Aufgaben:</span></div>

<ul>
<li style="padding: 0px 41px 14px;">test</li>
<li style="padding: 0px 41px 14px;">test2</li>
</ul>
```

I want to change the **padding** of the div-box. But because I am in a framework I can't just change it in the html code. I need to change it via javascript. In fact there are many div boxes, not just this one. But the div-box I want to change has no ID, so I can't just change this one DIV.

But I want to change every DIV which comes right in fron of an `<ul>`-Tag. Is this possible?

To be concrete:

1. Search all ul-tags
2. Find the div which comes right before the ul-tag in the DOM
3. Change the padding of this div-box.

**Update:**

I really forgot to mention that I need a solution without JQuery. Sorry.

Comment: So you shouldn't really not have tagged your question with jQuery... ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use as selector and method:

```
$('div + ul').prev().css('padding', 0)
```

### -jsFiddle-

Or still in jQuery:

```
$('ul').prev('div').css('padding', 0) // i guess it would be slower, if it really matters...
```

Comment: Great! What if I want padding like this? padding: 0px 41px 14px;

Comment: @progNewbie - see my comment, you can apply `css` to it.

Comment: @progNewbie Just pass it to `css()` method. Now your div has already this padding set inline, so here i use other one: https://jsfiddle.net/weemoLya/5/  And here example in plain js: https://jsfiddle.net/weemoLya/6/  because obviously you aren't using jQuery in your posted code

Comment: For me this plain js doesn't work. It also does not in jsfiddle..?

Comment: @progNewbie Maybe because [previousElementSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/previousElementSibling) method isn't standart, here is a polyfill: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9008846/1414562  But on which browser are you testing it?

Comment: But this (https://jsfiddle.net/weemoLya/7/) also doesn't work. I test it on firefox.

Comment: My bad, FF doesn't implement forEach loop on nodeList, so use: e.g https://jsfiddle.net/weemoLya/8/   Or to support all (modern) browsers, you'd need both workaround: https://jsfiddle.net/weemoLya/9/  Or better use jQuery which handles it for you :)  This is the method that will work on all browsers IE6> on jq 1.x version: `$('ul').prev('div').css('padding', 0)`

Answer (score 1):

You can select the div with .prev() and change the padding with .css()

```
$("ul:eq(0)").prev().css("padding","*values*")
```

Answer (score 1):

What is possible to do with jQuery is possible with javascript.

```
var ul = document.querySelector('div + ul');
for(var i=0,el;el=ul.parentNode.children[i];++i){
  if(el === ul){
    //this is your div. Do whatever you want with it.
    var div = ul.parentNode.children[i-1];
    break;
  }
}

//if you have to handle many such elements
var uls = document.querySelectorAll('div + ul');
for(var j=0,ul;ul = uls[j];++j){
   for(var i=0,el;el=ul.parentNode.children[i];++i){
...
```